# cocos 2d detect simoultaneous touch in 2 sprites - like in fruit ninja game

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, touch, sprite

I want to know how can i detect when i touch 2 sprites simoultaneously in cocos2d. Im creating a game similar to fruit ninja and i want to add some bonus points when i smash two sprites simultaneously with my blade. I have tried something like that but it doesn't work:

```
(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    //Add a new body/atlas sprite at the touched location
    for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];

        //[self addNewSpriteAtPosition: location];
        [_blade dim:YES];
        [_bladeSparkle stopSystem];

        for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
        {

            if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
                PolygonSprite *sprite = (PolygonSprite*)b->GetUserData();
                NSLog(@"sprite entered, exited %d, %d",sprite.sliceEntered,sprite.sliceExited);
                if(sprite.type == kTypeTrapPrice && CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, location))
                {
                    NSLog(@"TOUCHED");


                    noTouch++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
     // NSLog(@"NO TOUCH %i",noTouch);
    [self clearSlices];
}
```

Comment: What actually happens? Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the following tutorial?

http://www.raywenderlich.com/14302/how-to-make-a-game-like-fruit-ninja-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-1

Plus there are lots of other great ones there.